# How can I get the sender of an email gmail python API

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api

```
def getbodyinbox():
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    label_name = "READ-BY-SCRIPT"
    label_id = 'Label_8507504117657095973'
    results = service.users().messages().list(
        userId='me', q="-label:"+label_name, maxResults=1).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])
    body = []
    if not messages:
        body = "no messages"
        return body
    else:
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(
                userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            labels = msg['labelIds']
            if "INBOX" in labels:
                headers = msg['payload']['headers']
                headers = str(headers)
                print(headers)
                if "class_ix" in headers:
                    body.append(msg['payload']['parts'])
                    if 'data' in body[0][0]['body']:
                        body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                            body[0][0]['body']['data'])
                    elif 'data' in body[0][1]['body']:
                        body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                            body[0][1]['body']['data'])
                    body = str(body)

                        
                    return body


print(getbodyinbox())
```

This is my code so far with the parts that get the credentials removed. It gets the body of the most recent email without a label 'READ-BY-SCRIPT' that also has the label INBOX. How can I adapt it to get the sender of the email?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sender of an email in **[Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource:-message) -> [payload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#messagepart) -> [headers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.Header)**

You just need to match the `header['name'] == 'From'`  and gets its equivalent `header['value']`

**Sample [Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource:-message) Response Body (for Headers):**

```
{
  "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
      
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "User \u003cuser@email.com\u003e"
      },
      
      .....

      {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": "TEST EMAIL"
      },

    ],

  }
}
```

**Sample Code:**

```
headers = msg['payload']['headers']

for header in headers: # getting the Sender
    if header['name'] == 'From':
        msg_from = header['value']
        break
```

### Note:

Header sender value has this kind of format: `"User \u003cuser@email.com\u003e"`

You can get the sender's name by parsing the string from the start until `\u003c` tag, while you can get the sender's email by parsing the string that is enclosed in `\u003c` and `\u003e` tags.